# How to create a batch file from .exe file?

Tags: batch-file

I want to know simply how to create a batch file from .exe file?

Comment: Batch files are as the name implies a batch of commands to run together.  An executable is a binary file. What do you mean create and .exe file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean you want to create a new batch file from an unrelated existing executable file (in other words, the batch file does something different), you do it the way you create *any* file. In C, you'd use `fopen`, `fwrite` and `fclose` to create your new file and write whatever batch file commands you want to it.

If you mean you want to create a batch file that "intercepts" your exe file, you can do that too. If your executable file is `pax.exe`, you can simply rename it to `pax2.exe` and create a batch file called `pax.cmd` thus:

```
@echo off
pax2.exe
```

This will allow you to do arbitrary actions before and after your executable runs but there are things to watch out for such as executables that return control before they're actually finsihed.

If, however, you're talking about converting an arbitrary executable into a batch file that performs the same task, that's much more difficult. Unless you have the source code or a very good specification on how the executable works, you're going to have a lot of trouble.

Automating the conversion for anything but the simplest executable will be insanely difficult.

---

And, if you want a link to a batch file that runs your executable, just create the batch file (say in `c:\bin\pax.cmd`) containing:

```
@echo off
c:\bin\pax.exe
```

and then create a shortcut to it from wherever you want (such as the desktop). You could even put the batch file itself in your desktop directory but I'm not a big fan of that. However, to each their own.

Comment: I want to make a .bat file to run .exe file...
I have test.exe file in my Desktop. I want to create test.bat on my desktop, so when i click on it, it will run the .exe file.
Is this possible?

Comment: @Davideg: yes, that's similar to my second option above and almost exactly identical to my fourth option, which appears to have miraculously and spontaneously formed for no reason whatsoever :-)

Comment: so, you mean that I create test.txt file and write on it the 2 lines:

@echo off
c:\bin\test.exe

then I rename this file to test.bat. and that`s it.

I did this scenario but it didn`t work out.
Did I forget any detail?

Comment: @Davideg, that was sample code I gave, it's unlikely that your `test.exe` file will be in `c:\bin`. You need to put its _actual_ path into the batch file.

Comment: @paxdiablo, What you mean by "unlikely that your test.exe file will be in c:\bin". you always mention c:\bin => is it essential to use this directory or not.

Comment: No, it's not. You should use directories suited to your environment. I have a `c:\bin` because I always create one to dump all those little goodies that I need without having to add hundreds of different directories to my PATH. You should put your batch file where you want (e.g., create a `My Documents\batchfiles` for it). The batch file itself should contain the _full path of the executable._ Example, if the executable was `c:\europa\eclipse.exe`, _that's_ what you would use. You need to use the path where your `test.exe` actually is.